# I have a select query that gets me a single column as a result. Now I need to put all those column values in CSV format

Tags: mysql, sql

```
--------------------
- # - timesheet_id -
--------------------
- 1 -      1       -
--------------------
- 2 -      2       -
--------------------
```

Now the format required should be in "1,2" which is nothing but the values of timesheet_id.
Somebody please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timesheet_ID) as TimeList
FROM   tableName
INTO   OUTFILE '/tmp/timeIDList.csv'  -- file output path
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

SOURCE

- [Save MySQL query results into a text or CSV file](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/)
- [Export CSV directly from MySQL](https://ariejan.net/2008/11/27/export-csv-directly-from-mysql)

Comment: but I dont want to export them to a file. The results that gets generated will be passed to another query immediately.

Comment: i was confused of your title. anyway, just wrap the result in a subquery, eg. `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timesheet_ID) as TimeList
FROM   tableName) x WHERE...`

Comment: thanks man. that GROUP_CONCAT function worked for me. that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

In mySQL you could use GROUP_CONCAT for that

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timesheet_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM table
```